# Why is Laravel's flash message not outputting 0?

Tags: laravel

I have a function that counts the amount of free space for uploading files.

If the user tries to upload, for example, 5 files, and there is only space for one, then a flash message will appear with the amount of free space - 1.

But if there is no space, I expect to see 0, but the flash message is not displayed at all

`dd` returns the correct number and I pass that value to flash

```
$count = $this->checkCountAdditionalPhotosInProduct($product, $request->additional_photos, $this->imgPath($userId), $uploadService);
//dd($count);
return redirect()->back()->with('count', $count);
```

And view

```
@if (session('count'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert" >
        Your free space - {{ session('freeSpace') }}
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
@endif
```

The product stores a serialized array of photo links. I check if there is a string in the product field, I deserialize it, count the number of elements. Dalle subtract the received amount from the constant which is equal to 5 and return the result

```
public function checkCountAdditionalPhotosInProduct (Product $product): int
{
    $currentProductPhotos = $product->additional_photos ? count((array)unserialize($product->additional_photos)) : 0;
    $freePlace = self::TOTAL_PRODUCT_PHOTOS - $currentProductPhotos;
    return $freePlace;
}
```

Comment: $count returns the amount of free space, install using with(key,value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected and normal. When `count` is `0` and you want to retrieve it from the session, using `session('count')`, it returns `0` as you need but the issue resides in the `if` statement: `@if (session('count'))`, which will result in `@if 0` which evaluates to `FALSE` thus the code portion inside that if statement **WILL NEVER** get executed when `session('count')` returns `0`.

The fix is fairly simple, just change this:

```php
@if (session('count'))
```

Into this:

```php
@if (session('count') !== null)
```

That's because the `session()` function returns `NULL` (by default) when the wanted `key` (in your case the key is `count`) cannot be found in the session.

> Please be advised that the default value returned by the [`session()`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#the-global-session-helper) function when the `key` cannot be found in the session can be customized by specifying what you want to return in that case by passing the wanted default value as the second parameter. Learn more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/session#the-global-session-helper).

Comment: I guess it's time for me to go to bed) Thanks for the help

Comment: @Martaakitaj You're welcome! Glad I managed to help.